# How to impliment a stringlist property in a custom delphi component?

Tags: delphi, components, tstringlist

I am creating my first custom Delphi component. Its basically a custom Tpanel with header and lines text displayed on it.

I want to be able to add multiple lines text using a stringlist.

When testing the component I cannot get the text lines to display on the panel when adding lines: NewLinesText.add('line1 text')

It does however work when I create and populate a new stringlist at runtime and then assign it to my control : controlPanelitem.NewLinesText = MyNewStringlist

I want to be able to add lines like this: NewLinesText.add('line1 text')

I am using Delphi 7 professional on WinXP. See code below.

Any help would be appreciated!

`unit ControlPanelItem;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, ExtCtrls, Graphics, AdvPanel, StdCtrls,
  Windows,Forms,Dialogs;

type
  tControlPanelItem = class(TAdvPanel)
  private
    fLinesText : TStrings;
    procedure SetLinesText(const Value: TStrings);
    procedure SetText;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property NewLinesText  : TStrings read FLinesText write SetLinesText;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [tControlPanelItem]);
end;

constructor tControlPanelItem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fLinesText := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor tControlPanelItem.Destroy;
begin
  fLinesText.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure tControlPanelItem.SetLinesText(const Value: TStrings);
begin
  fLinesText.Assign(value);
  SetText;
end;

procedure tControlPanelItem.SetText;
var
   count : Integer;
begin
 for count := 0 to fLinesText.Count - 1 do
  ShowMessage(fLinesText.strings[count]);

end;

end.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do

```
procedure SetLines(Lines: TStrings);
begin
  FLinesText.Assign(Lines);
  // Repaint, update or whatever you need to do.
end;
```

You may also need to set the `OnChange` property of the `FLines` (do this in the constructor of your custom control, as soon as you have created it). Set it to any `TNofifyEvent`-compatible (private or protected, I guess) procedure of your component. In this procedure, you can do the repainting, updating etc. you need.

That is, do

```
constructor TControlPanelItem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FLinesText := TStringList.Create;
  TStringList(FLinesText).OnChange := LinesChanged;
end;

procedure TControlPanelItem.LinesChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Repaint, update or whatever you need to do.
end;
```

Comment: I am already doing that. See procedure tControlPanelItem.SetLinesText that calls SetText. (procedure SetText is not complete. Im just using showmessage to see if it is working)

Comment: OK, I didn't see that. (As you know, the code wasn't pretty a few minutes ago!) But I cannot see any `OnChange`?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your quick response. FLinesText is a stringlist and does not have an onchange property as far as I know?

Comment: @Delphiguy: Yes, it has: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStringList_Events. But since the variable is declared as a `TStrings` (which does **not** have this event), you need to tell the compiler/IDE that it is a `TStringList` explicitly. See my update.

Comment: This is confusing. FLinesText is declared as  TStrings that does not have a onchange property, however, FLinesText is created as a TStringList that does have the onchange event. Should I type cast?

Comment: @Delphiguy: Yes, I saw that before you even posted your comment. See my update.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you so much! that worked perfectly! Been struggling with that the whole day!